# Which function has superseded the trans_break function in the scales package for R?

Tags: r

This might not be a coding question per se, but I don't know where else to ask it.

The documentation of the `scales` pacakge for R says that the `trans_breaks` function has been superseded. However, I can't seem to find what is the new, better alternative function. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the only specialized breaks-calculating function for transformed scales is `log_breaks()`. `trans_new()` uses `breaks = extended_breaks` by default.  The only transformations I can find that overrides this default are `log_trans()` (which is called by `log2_trans()` and `log10_trans()`, which uses `log_breaks()`, and the date/time transformations (`date_trans`, `hms_trans`, `time_trans`), which use `time_breaks` or `breaks_pretty` ...

```r
fn_compare <- function(f1, f2) identical(deparse(f1), deparse(f2))
trans_list <- apropos("_trans")
invisible(sapply(trans_list,
   function(f) {
      cat(f,": ")
      d <- deparse(get(f))
      w <- grep("trans_new", d)
      if (length(w) == 0) cat("\n") else cat(d[w:(w+1)], "\n")
   }
))
```